# How do you handle a temporary outage of a member of the replica set in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

When one of the servers in the replica set is taken down or goes down, the application times out trying to connect to the replica set.

don't know what to do differently. Is there a programming pattern for handling this? Running Mongodb 3.4.24 on Windows servers.

Comment: How do you connect? Usually the driver re-connects automatically when service goes down. How many members do you have? As long as the majority is up and running, everything should work fine. BTW, MongoDB version 3.4 is end-of-life for many years.

Comment: We have 3 members in the collection. Connecting with .net client. The connection string looks like this :  mongodb://<user>:<pass>@MONGO001.DEV.COMPANY.org,MONGO002.DEV.COMPANY.org,MONGO003.DEV.COMPANY.org/my-dev-comp-services?replicaSet=rs1&connectTimeoutMS=2000

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `readPreference=primaryPreferred` to the connection string.

In case when the primary is not available, then the driver should re-connect automatically.